# Aframe how to adjust canvas in vr mode

Tags: aframe

hello guys I have a problem in aframe vr mode using android webbrowser.. I dont know how to hide all buttons from the right.. it looks like the fallowing.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpCzb.jpg)
I already tried adding code like `document.body.requestFullscreen();` but it doest not work.. any help?

Comment: Have you tried A-Frame master: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@220998a93d9237bbbe70e8062c48e73f73ca7924/dist/aframe-master.min.js This should have been fixed: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/4090

Comment: it fixed on android mobile browser but it has a bug on iphone. it doest not matter I wrote a code detecting if the client is using iphone or android and set the aframe source depends on client device.. thanks for the help.